# Flask - websocket doesn't work correctly in a real server

Tags: flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I've developed a WebApp with Flask, where different threads check a status and, if something changes they send a new json to the client. Then the client, with the javascript, can update the html page.
Running the app in my LAN, different clients connect and everything work correctly.

If I run the app on a real server (such as AWS, by using "flask run --host=0.0.0.0" ), the clients can connect and show the web page, but they don't receive the json sent by the socket of the webapp.

In the WebApp, a thread sends the new json by calling a function that uses:

```
socketio.emit('update', {'number': new_json_FE}, namespace='/test')
```

While the javascript receives this message (and does something) in this way:

```
socket.on('update', function(msg) { ....}
```

It is very strange that the clients connected in the LAN receive correctly all the json sent by the socket, while in the web not: they only receive the json when they connect to, and I have to upload the page (they don't receive the socket messages).

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There isn't enough information to identify the issue. For example, how do we know if the clients are connecting to the correct server when establishing the WebSocket... maybe they are trying to connect to a constant address that routes to the development server?

Comment: First of all, you can't start a Socket.IO server with `flask run`. See the documentation. Second, there is a section on troubleshooting in the Flask-SocketIO documentation that shows how to enable detailed logs. The logs will be helpful in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your response! I think the problem is due how I manage the diffrent threads. In particular, I need there are different threads in my server (defined in a class), and when something appens, a thread has to use the socketio.emit to send a json. What is the best approach to do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against the use of threads like you have described for this situation.

Instead I would probably create a new program, StatusUpdater, that is always running and which is connected via socket to your Flask-SocketIO backend. When it finds a change in status it sends w/e signal or payload it needs to, through a socket, to the Flask-Socketio server. The SocketIO server upon receipt of this StatusUpdater payload can then send a broadcast to all connected clients notifying the client of the update.